# Http provider doesn't reach my localhost server

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got a provider that uses the Http service to perform a GET operation over a localhost server:

```
 requestAchievedCombined(config){
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

            const URL = "localhost:3000";
            const query = "?collection=achieved_combined&query=columns";
            this.http.get(URL+"/api"+query).subscribe( response => {
                // TODO: check data integriy
                console.log(">> API RES: ", response)
                resolve(response);

            }, err => this.errorHandler(err, reject));
        })
    }
```

The server is hosted in localhost:3000 and running, and it works perfectly when called from the navigator with that same GET query string... it returns some JSON.

Thing is, when I execute my Angular app, this gives me the following error:

```
ERROR [DataRequester] =>  
{…}
_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot GET /function%20URL()%20%7B%20%20%20%20[native%20code]%7D/api</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
headers: Object { _headers: Map, _normalizedNames: Map }
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
type: 2
url: "http://localhost:4200/function%20URL()%20%7B%20%20%20%20[native%20code]%7D/api?collection=achieved_combined&query=columns"
__proto__: Object { constructor: Response(), toString: Response.prototype.toString() }
```

Do anybody know why this happens? What am I doing wrong? I'm using the latest Angular version.

pd: yes I tried putting http:// before localhost in the URL.

EDIT: After changing the url to http://localhost:3000 and call the property in a proper way (I was forgetting the this. thing), I could manage to communicate with the server, but now I'm having this issue:

```
ERROR [DataRequester] =>  
{…}
_body: error
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
explicitOriginalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { __zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:3000/api?collection=achieved_combined&query=columns", readyState: 4, … }
isTrusted: true
lengthComputable: false
loaded: 0
originalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { __zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:3000/api?collection=achieved_combined&query=columns", readyState: 4, … }
target: XMLHttpRequest { __zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:3000/api?collection=achieved_combined&query=columns", readyState: 4, … }
timeStamp: 3687.8557595446277
total: 0
type: "error"
__proto__: ProgressEventPrototype { lengthComputable: Getter, loaded: Getter, total: Getter, … }
headers: Object { _headers: Map, _normalizedNames: Map }
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: 3
url: null
__proto__: Object { constructor: Response(), toString: Response.prototype.toString() }
```

Answer (score 1):

URL is a global function that gets "called". Try renaming the URL var to url and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed this thing, but now I'm getting another error; let me edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first thing wrong was that I wasn't calling the URL property in a good way: actually, it wasn't in the method but in the class, and I was forgetting the "this.", so I wasn't pointing to the right variable.

Secondly, fixed my edit simply setting up CORS in my express server:

```
        app.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            next();
});
```

Now my Angular app correctly gets the data!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just passing by to give you some code

```
requestAchievedCombined(config): Observable<any> {
  const URL = "localhost:3000";
  const query = "?collection=achieved_combined&query=columns";
  return this.http.get(URL+"/api"+query)
    .map( response => {
      // TODO: check data integriy
      console.log(">> API RES: ", response)
      return response;
    }, err => this.errorHandler(err))
    // .toPromise() // If you still want your cherished promise
    ;
}
```

I've changed your function to simplify it : you should use Observables instead of Promises. I know, I was skeptical at first too, but Observables are way more powerful than promises. and if you still don't like it, simply call `.toPromise()` right after the map operator, it will still be clearer ;)

Other than that, Could you post the trace of your error instead of the payload ? We need the error message to know what is happening.